# Liquid dynamic filename is not accepted

Tags: jekyll, template-engine, liquid

When i use

```
{% include folder1/folder1_1/img.jpg %}
```

it works perfectly, But when i try to generate the filename dynamically let's say :

```
{%capture filename %} {{'folder1/folder1_1/'}}{{ images[0] }}{{ '.jpg' }}{% endcapture %}

{% include {{ filename }}  %}
```

with `images[0] = 'img'` for example, i get the error that says :

```
Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains 
invalid characters or sequences ...
```

I Don't understand why including file by providing the complete path(static path) works whereas generating the filename dynamically won't work !

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research on the internet it seems that dynamic filename paths can't be added due to the fact that the included files are calculated and added at the **compilation phase** and not at **run time phase**.

And compilation phase means dynamic paths aren't yet recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more luck with :

```
{% capture filename %}folder1/folder1_1/'{{ images[0] }}.jpg'{% endcapture %}
{% include {{ filename }}  %}
```